# Mass editing the From condition in rules

Tags: vba, outlook

I am able to add email addresses but I cannot delete them.

I am getting run time error 13 mismatch on my remove code.

```
Sub CHANGERULES()
    Dim objStores As Outlook.Stores
    Dim objStore As Outlook.Store
    Dim objRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim objRuleCondition As Outlook.RuleCondition
    Dim objToFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition

    Set objRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()

    For i = objRules.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objRule = objRules(i)

        For Each objRuleCondition In objRule.Conditions
            If objRuleCondition.ConditionType = olConditionFrom Then

                objRuleCondition.Recipients.Add ("123@123.com")
                objRuleCondition.Recipients.Remove ("456@456.com")
                objRuleCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll

                On Error Resume Next
                objRules.Save
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when you use '''objrulecondition.recipients.remove''', it will specify an index value instead of a string/variant value. thus the solution to delete an e-mail should be

`objrulecondition.recipeints.remove (1)`